# Control access to a custom blocks edit page

Tags: 7, blocks, hooks, users

I have a small module which creates and adds some custom settings for a block. Now I would like to control access to this blocks edit page. All users should be able to display the block, while changing the actual the configuration only should be available to certain users. 
Since I am not able to use `hook_permission()` I am not really sure how to best solve this so any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

I have tried this without any success:

```
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  return array(
    'MYBLOCK' => array(
    'info' => t('MYBLOCK'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    ),
  );
}
```

When I clear the cache and tries to go to the blocks edit page the url changes but nothing happens. It is like I am still standing on the block overview page?

```
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer MYBLOCK' => array(
    'title' => t('Administer MYBLOCK'),
    'description' => t('Administer MYBLOCK settings.'),
   ),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/structure/block/manage/MYMODULE/MYBLOCK/configure']['access arguments'] = array('administer MYBLOCK');
}
```

**Edit**

If I use `user_access()` in `hook_block_configure()` I almost achieve what I want. I don't know if this would be a valid way to solve this problem:

```
function MYMODULE_block_configure($delta = '') {
  $form = array();
  if ($delta == 'MYBLOCK') {
    if (!user_access('administer MYBLOCK')) {
      drupal_set_message(t('You are not allowed to edit the @block block.', array('@block' => $delta)), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
      drupal_goto('admin/structure/block/manage');
      drupal_exit();
    }
    // Setup form for the block here.
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: How does the PATH look like for somebody who wants to EDIT such blocks?

Comment: _"Since I am not able to use hook_permission"_ - why?

Comment: You could accomplish this by using hook_permission() and hook_menu_alter().

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing - Could you add an answer which show an example on how to do this?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - I thought that `hook_permission()` could not be used to control access to a block. Is it safe to assume that the path to the block always will be the same? In that case I guess hooking into `hook_menu()` would work or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Cyclonecode your question is about ***edit*** of blocks, so which path does one use to request Drupal to EDIT some block?

Comment: If this is a block you've provided through a module, then you can always guarantee the block's path. However, if it was created through the frontend of the site, then your path will be `admin/structure/block/manage/block/BLOCK_ID/configure`. You could still use this path directly if you would like but just be aware that if the block were to be deleted and recreated from the frontend of the site, the BLOCK_ID would change.

Comment: @Cyclonecode do you define the block in your module as well? (There is some discussion here on wheter this a custom block build via the UI, or a module provided block.) If your module defines it, you can use `hook_menu` instead of `hook_menu_alter`.

Comment: @Neograph734 - Yes I define the block in the module. I will try to use `hook_menu()` instead. But shouldn't `hook_menu_alter()` also work?

Comment: Yes it should, but provides some unneeded overhead. Can you include your hook_menu code? (At least the part of the block configuration page.)

Comment: @Neograph734 - I am using `hook_block_configure()` to create the custom form which is showned on the blocks edit page. I just tried to use `hook_menu()` adding the route to the blocks edit page but I am getting the same response as when using `hook_menu_alter()` nothing happens and I am not showned the edit page?

Comment: @Neograph734 - My guess would be that since `hook_block_configure()` returns the form for the block I would need to add something like `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form'` or similar in order for this to work as expected.

Comment: If you configuration page is not defined in hook_menu, nothing proposed here will help. (Everything assumes you have a menu entry.) It is correct that you need a page callback. Plenty of examples online on how to do that and what `page attributes` you have to provide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63700/discussion-between-cyclonecode-and-neograph734).

Comment: I am sorry, I have an appointment in a few minutes so I cannot help you for now... I will see if I can get back later today. Feel free to update the question with your new findings. Good luck.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Is it possible for you to give us a copy of the code via something like pastebin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve this using [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x), instead I created a custom permission for my block and then used [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7.x) in the [`hook_block_configure()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7.x) to check if the user has access or not:

```
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer MYBLOCK' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer MYBLOCK'),
    ),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_block_configure($delta = '') {
  $form = array();
  if ($delta == 'MYBLOCK') {
    // Check if user has permission to configure the block.
    if (!user_access('administer MYBLOCK')) {
      // In case the user does not have correct permission we
      // returns to the block overview screen and displays a warning
      // message.
      drupal_set_message(t('You are not allowed to edit the @block block.', array('@block' => $delta)), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
      drupal_goto('admin/structure/block/manage');
      drupal_exit();
    }
    // Setup form for the block here.
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function my_module_permission() {
  return [
    'my_module_custom_permission' => [
      'title' => t('My Module Custom Permission'),
      'description' => t('Explain what this permission allows the user to do.'),
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function my_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/structure/block/manage/block/5/configure']['access arguments'] = ['my_module_custom_permission'];
}
```

If you use the code above, follow the steps below.

#### Steps

1. Replace all instances of 'my_module_custom_permission' to a machine name that makes sense.
2. Update the 'title' and 'description' for the custom permission.
3. Replace all instances of the word 'my_module' with your module's machine name.
4. Change the `$items` path from what I have to the block path you are trying to update.

#### Important to note

If the block you are editing was created from the frontend of the Drupal website, then it can be deleted. If it gets deleted and then recreated, the block's ID will change. Which in turn changes the path to the block's configuration page.

#### Testing

Make sure to give your test user the permission we've just made and make sure they can edit the block configuration. Also, test a user who does not have the permission and make sure they can not edit the block configuration.

Comment: The above does not seem to work? The altered menu item is `$items['admin/structure/block/manage/MYMODULE/MYMODULEBLOCK/configure']['access arguments'] = array('mypermission');` and the only things that happens after I haved cleared the cache and trying to edit the block is that the actual form is not displayed? This block is created by the module through `hook_block_info()`.

Comment: I have updated the question with relevant information.